# Error in Ant file

Tags: java, ant

I have the following code in my build xml file

```
 <"/fail unless="java.home1_6" message="Property java.home1_6 must be set to a JDK of version 1.6"/>
      <"/echo message="Java home used for building JavaUtilities:${java.home1_6}"/>
        <"/property name="javac.executable" location="${java.home1_6}/../bin/javac.exe"/>
      <"/available file="${javac.executable}" property="javac.found"/>
      <"/fail unless="javac.found" message="javac.exe was not found"/>
```

but when I run the file it shows the following error

```
BUILD FAILED
D:\Mand\javautilities\build.xml:4: Property java.home1_6 must be set to a JDK of version 1.6
```

Comment: Your code is missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please set the JAVA_HOME environment variable in your machine. It is failing because the property JAVA_HOME is not set. If you do not want to set it at machine level, then set it in the build.xml file.

**UPDATE after the code has been posted**

Looks like you are using a property java.home1_6 in the build.xml file. You need to set that in the file by either using the properties file or [using the property task](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/property.html).

for e.g.

```
<property name="foo.dist" value="dist"/>
```

Comment: Thank you for the information But in the enviroment variable JAVA_HOME IS ALREADY SET TO 
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_41.
but it is still showing the error.

Comment: Can you print it in the command prompt? Do a set JAVA_HOME (Windows) or echo $JAVA_HOME (Unix). Do you see the value set? If so please post the code along with the question.

Comment: I RAN THE COMMAND THROUGH CMD AND IT SHOWS THE FOLLOWING JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_41